# Accepting foreign letters in Java?

Tags: java, string, boolean, system, symbols

I made a method that can detect numbers in a string. However, It does not accept strings with ÆØÅ letters. Any advice to make it accept it and easily integrated into my method?

```
public static boolean checkNumbers(String testString) {

        String numOnly = testString.replaceAll("\\p{Alpha}", "");
        try {
            double numVal = Double.valueOf(numOnly);
            System.out.println(testString + " contains numbers");
            return true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println(testString + " Contains no numbers");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use a locale that considers those characters as alphanumeric.

Comment: try use this: .replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");

Comment: @AdilOoze Thank you very much, brother. Your solution was easy and fixed my issue completely. God bless you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted in the comments:

you will need to change your `.replaceAll("\\p{Alpha}", "");`

to `.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");`